Proof of Khintchine’s inequality for sub-gaussians
I am trying to prove the exercise 2.6.6 of HDP book by Roman Vershynin. The exercise is as follows.

Actually the right hand side is easy to find, and the left hand side is also easy if given the red-underlined inequality. However, I totally have no idea how this inequality can be proven. It is neither Holder's  nor Jensen's form. Can anyone give me any hint about this one?

We have $\lVert Z \rVert_2 = (\mathbb{E}Z^2)^{1/2}, \lVert Z \rVert_1 = \mathbb{E}\vert Z \vert, \lVert Z \rVert_3 = (\mathbb{E}\vert Z \vert^3)^{1/3}$. The inequality is equivalent to:
$$
    \mathbb{E}(\vert Z \vert^2) \le (\mathbb{E}\vert Z \vert)^{1/2}(\mathbb{E}\vert Z \vert^3)^{1/2}
$$
This is a direct application of Holder inequality:
$$
    \mathbb{E}\vert XY \vert \le (\mathbb{E} \vert X \vert^p)^{1/p} (\mathbb{E}\vert Y \vert^q)^{1/q}
$$
where $p = q = 2$ and $X = \vert Z \vert^{1/2}, Y = \vert Z \vert^{3/2}$

Thanks a lot! That is also a very simple corollary of Holder's inequality... I just don't know why I can't come up with this
